# What is an HTTP header element?

Tags: java, apache, http, http-headers, setcookie

According to [this Apache documentation](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HeaderElement.html) "Some HTTP headers (such as the set-cookie header) have values that can be decomposed into multiple elements". I can't make much sense of this. For example, when I use the getElements() method on a "Set-Cookie" Header object that has a value of:

```
SESSIONID=abcdefg01234; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 09 Jun 2021 10:18:14 GMT
```

I get back an array of two `HeaderElement`s, one header element is:

```
SESSIONID=abcdefg01234; Path=/; Expires=Wed
```

and the other one is:

```
09 Jun 2021 10:18:14 GMT
```

How useful is this? On these `HeaderElement`s I can invoke methods like `getName()`, `getValue()`, `getParameterByName()` but what will be the value or parameters of **09 Jun 2021 10:18:14 GMT** ??? Also why is the valid parameter of the header **Expires=Wed, 09 Jun 2021 10:18:14 GMT** split into two? This seems wrong. Yet, when I do call header.getElements() on the header:

```
Set-Cookie: SESSIONID=abcdefg01234; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 09 Jun 2021 10:18:14 GMT
```

It becomes split into two header elements, as these are supposed to be comma separated... Still, I fail to find any better explanation of the concept of a header element than is [mentioned here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HeaderElement.html). What, then, are these header elements? Could anyone explain, please?

Comment: An example of where it does make sense is with the `Content-Type` header. This commonly appears as `Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1`. Likewise, the `Accept` header can assign a quality to each acceptable content type: `Accept: text/plain; q=0.5, text/html, text/x-dvi; q=0.8, text/x-c` (the last example comes from [RFC-2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)).

Answer (score 2):

What you're getting there is the header called "Cookie" which is one of the headers sent by the servers for previouslly set cookies. The format of this header's value is "cokkie1name=cookie1valie;cookie2name=cookie2value;" and so on for each of the cookies previouslly set.The actual value of the "Cookie" header is all that concatenated chain of cookie name/values separated by ";". Once you recuperate said value of said header, you can split it by ";" to get the name/value of each cookie. 
Now that being said, apparentlly when Apache's HttpCliont library's parsing of header values makes a known blunder here, and it wrongly splits by "," instead of ";". As the Apache guys sais on this forum thread, for them it's normal behaviour, if you want a different one make your own parser:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-810

Comment: i am very sorry, I did mention the "Set-Cookie" header in the first paragraph then I used "Cookie" in the last example... I edited that now

Answer (score 1):

What you are running into is a problem with Set-Cookie; it uses the delimiter "," in the wrong way.

A better example would be "Allow" or "Accept".

See http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p1-messaging-16.html#rfc.section.3.2.p.7 for more information.

Comment: Yes, I do have a problem with a Set-Cookie header. What I don't understand is what is a header element, since the org.apache.http.Header interface has the getElements() method and I can't see why? I can call all the good methods, such as getName() getValue() getParameterByName() on a HeaderElement, but not on the Header itself. So what is the concept of a header element. Why does it break a perfectly normal Set-Cookie header into useless two parts only because there is a comma in the Expires parameter....

Comment: Peter, this seems to refer to the elements of header fields that are defined to use list syntax, such as Accept. Set-Cookie is a problem in that it doesn't use that syntax, so it appears to be a bug in the Javadoc that it claims that it's usable here.

Due to historic reason, parsing cookie headers is very different from everything else, thus generic code isn't going to help here. See RFC 6265 for details.